# Magento 2 custom module Model not woking

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2

I am trying to create model in my custom plugin. Please check and let me know what I am doing wrong.

*Model/ReviewCat.php*

```
<?php

namespace Revoamerica\Categoryreview\Model;

class ReviewCat extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel implements \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{

    const CACHE_TAG = 'revoamerica_Categoty_post';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Revoamerica\Categoryreview\Model\ResourceModel\ReviewCat');
    }

    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

*Model/ResourceModel/ReviewCat.php*

```
<?php 

namespace Revoamerica\Categoryreview\Model\ResourceModel;

class ReviewCat extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{

    public function getCategoryReview(){
      $connection = $this->getConnection();
        $select = $connection->select()->from($this->getTable('review_detail'));
        return $connection->fetchAll($select);
         // $connection = $this->getConnection();
         //  $connection->select()->from($this->getTable('review_detail'))->join(
      //       ['detail' => $this->getTable('review')],
      //       'review_detail.review_id = detail.review_id',
      //       ['detail_id', 'title', 'detail', 'nickname', 'customer_id']
      //   );
        //  )->join(['e'=>$this->getTable('catalog_product_entity')],'cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id',['entity_id'])
           // ->join(['cat_index'=>$this->getTable('catalog_category_product_index')],'cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.category_id IN (23,8,35,2) AND cat_index.is_parent=1',['cat_index'])->where('review.entity_pk_value=e.entity_id');

        // return 'testtt';

    }
 }
```

*Plugin/ReviewPlugin.php*

```
<?php

namespace Revoamerica\Categoryreview\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Collection as ReviewCollection;
use Revoamerica\Categoryreview\Model\ResourceModel\ReviewCat as ReviewCat;

class ReviewPlugin extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
{    

     /**
     * Review collection
     *
     * @var ReviewCollection
     */
    protected $_reviewsCollection;
    protected $_reviewscategory;

    /**
     * Review resource model
     *
     * @var \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory
      * @var \Revoamerica\Categoryreview\Model\ResourceModel\ReviewCatFactory
     */
    protected $_reviewsColFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
     * @param \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param \Revoamerica\Categoryreview\Model\ResourceModel\ReviewCatFactory $reviewCatFactory
     * @param array $data
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Revoamerica\Categoryreview\Model\ResourceModel\ReviewCatFactory $reviewCatFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_reviewsColFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->_reviewscategory = $reviewCatFactory;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $urlEncoder,
            $jsonEncoder,
            $string,
            $productHelper,
            $productTypeConfig,
            $localeFormat,
            $customerSession,
            $productRepository,
            $priceCurrency,
            $data
        );
    }

    public function aroundGetReviewsCollection(\Magento\Review\Block\Product\View $subject, callable $proceed)
    {
        $record=$this->_reviewscategory->create()->getCategoryReview();
        print_r($record);
        die("tetst");

        echo $this->getProduct()->getId();
        print_r($this->getProduct()->getCategoryIds());
        die("hjgjh");

        // logging to test override  
      if (null === $this->_reviewsCollection) {
            $this->_reviewsCollection = $this->_reviewsColFactory->create()->addStoreFilter(
                $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
            )->addStatusFilter(
                \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
            )->addEntityFilter(
                'product',
                $this->getProduct()->getId()
            )->setDateOrder();
        }
        return $this->_reviewsCollection;
    }

}
?>
```

I am using this function to assess model resource function. but it's not working.

> $record=$this->_reviewscategory->create()->getCategoryReview();

Comment: which error are you facing?

Comment: My log file showing this error
[2018-07-25 12:04:24] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://localhost/magento2.1/inez-full-zip-jacket.html","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []

Comment: Can you please let me know how to call model in plugin

Comment: The debug.log output is worthless here. Can you post the system.log & exception.log output? Also, set your system in developer mode, if you haven't yet.